# mPDF hide print and download

Tags: mpdf

I have code use to be show pdf on browser like these

```
require_once('../../library/mpdf60/mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4-L','','','4','4','2','0'); 
$html .= '<div class="row">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center" witdh="150%">
                            <b>SURAT JALAN</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">'.strtoupper($company).'</td>
                        <td width="5%" rowspan="4" valign="top">Kepada :</td>
                        <td width="35%">'.strtoupper($tolengkap).'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.strtoupper($Address1).'</td>
                        <td rowspan="3">'.strtoupper($Alamat).'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.strtoupper($Address2).'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Telp '.$Telp.' Fax '.$Fax.'</td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
              </div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
```

and it working, but my problem is i wanna disable option tools like print or download. I just wanna preview only. I try using

```
$mpdf->SetDisplayPreferences('/HideMenubar/HideToolbar/DisplayDocTitle');
```

But it seems doin nothing. Can anyone help me, i need disable download and print. Only just view.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likey not possible to disable download.

Use `Mpdf::SetProtection` and omit all options you want to disable.

See the [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Use $mpdf->SetVisibility('screenonly'); to disable print and download